# System help not rendering in drupal 7

Tags: theming

I'm having a problem where my system help block is not properly rendering messages in my main template. It works fine when using my administrative theme, but not in the standard one. When I print_r my $_SESSION variable I get the following:

```
[fb_devel] => Array
    (
        [FB_OP_POST_INIT] => 280
    )
[batches] => Array
    (
        [90] => 1
    )
[updates_remaining] => Array
    (
    )
[messages] => Array
    (
        [warning] => Array
            (
                [0] => For easier theme development, the theme registry is being rebuilt on every page request. It is <em>extremely</em> important to <a href="/admin/appearance/settings/cigarnews">turn off this feature</a> on production websites.
            )

    )
```

)

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages are displayed in a block, check that this block is in a region and that region is displayed in your theme.

Comment: I have confirmed that my block for system help (the block normally responsible for this) is in my style and placed on my page in a region. It's just not populating.

Comment: have you <?php print $messages; ?> in your page.tpl.php?

Comment: <?php print $messages; ?> did it. I was under the impression that the "system help" block was responsible for the messages; not the $messages variable.